# Bootstrap - hide element on portrait orientation and show on landscape

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide images on mobile devices in portrait orientation but show on landscape.

How it is possible with Bootstrap ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bootstrap don't have orientation based classes. But you can simply write them yourself using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in css.

```
@media (orientation:landscape) {
    .hide-on-landscape {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (orientation:portrait) {
    .hide-on-portrait {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: How could you get this to work on mobile devices only? Currently this doesn't take into account the viewport.

Comment: @CraigMayers You can simply mix it with bootstrap classes. Like: <div class="hide-on-landscape visible-xs">

Comment: How about @media(max-width: 480px)